# Apple Mail displaying � instead of accented characters

Tags: macos, mail.app, font

We do our correspondence mainly in French and this happens to me a lot. I type a message with accented characters, and my client receives the text but with all the accents replaced by a � (black diamond with white ?)

Here's an example...

Pour faire suite � notre conversation, voici les compl�ments d'information concernant la banni�re.

How can we stop this from happening?

Comment: Great problem. Might you list the OS and version of mail on the compose side? Also if you are sending plain text mail or HTML. Bonus would be to narrow down the receiver's OS and mail version - but let's start with your side in case it is an easy setting. When I view your post on my iPad - I get black squares with white empty centers. It seems we might have a quick solution if we can help you figure out what character set and encoding you want to communicate in for maximum readability.

Comment: Alos what are the Content-Type s of the MIME parts and the ASCII/Unicode of the missing characters

Comment: Might you also relate what encoding you are using? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33885/how-to-get-apple-mail-to-display-unicode-characters-reliably-for-different-peopl